# Change input value on hover CSS

Tags: php, css

Value of button gives me name of button on site. I want to change this button name on hover but i have no idea how to do it.

```
echo '<form id="pszycisk" method="POST" >';
           echo "<input id='submit' class='$przycisk' name ='obejrzane' type='submit' value='$przycisk' > "; 
         echo '</form>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to change the name on hover with `onmouseover` event and it can change back to the previous name with `onmouseout` event.

```js
var submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit')
var submitBtnOriValue = document.getElementById('submit').value;

submitBtn.onmouseover  = function () {
    submitBtn.value = "hovered"
}
submitBtn.onmouseout  = function() {
    submitBtn.value = submitBtnOriValue;
}
```

```html
<input id='submit' class='$przycisk' name ='obejrzane' type='submit' value='not hover' >
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a pure css solution you can do something like this. Place two buttons in the same position, one is hidden by default and only shows when the visible one is hovered:

```css
.button-container {
  position: relative;
}
.hover-hide-me,
.hover-show-me {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100px;
}
.hover-show-me {
  display: none;
}
.hover-hide-me:hover + .hover-show-me {
  display: block;
}
.hover-show-me:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <div class="button-container">
        <input type="submit" value="NOT HOVER" class="hover-hide-me">
        <input type="submit" value="HOVER" class="hover-show-me">
    </div>
</body>
```

The best solution is to use javascript, like in the other answer provided. This is just a trick if you want to stick to css.
Regards.